# Saving Column Order in Win 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I changed the order of columns in Windows 10 File Explorer but the old (default?) order returns when I reopen Explorer. Is there a way to save my preferred column order? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder in question, and access the "Folder Options" dialog, via:
(Click View in the ribbon, click the Options button, and click `Change folder and search options`.)

Click the `View` tab, and click the `Reset Folders` button. Click `Yes`.

This resets the folder view settings for all folders that are of the same type (eg. pictures). And resetting folder views can be necessary sometimes to clear corruption of folder view settings, or if you exceed the folder view settings storage limit (If I recall correctly, max is 5000)

If nothing helps, you can completely reset the folder view settings using the Vbscript [**here**](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-folder-views-bags-windows/).

Note: The above fixes don't help if the sort order issue you're facing is for music folders containing .mp3 files *AND* sorted by a metadata field (like Contributing artist, album etc). This is a known issue in Windows 10, and no solution yet as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks w32sh. However the "Reset Folders" button says "Do you want to reset all folders of this type to the DEFAULT view settings?" DEFAULT is what I DON'T want. The Vbscript solution looks like it might do the same and looks complicated enough for me to mess it up.

Comment: Yes. It effects all folders that use the same type/template. (example..pictures.) No issues, go ahead and clear them. You can configure the view settings and apply to all folders again.

Comment: I think that did it! Actually all I had to do was make my changes and click the   "Apply to Folders" button in the "View" tab. Thanks again for your super-quick response:)

Comment: Very welcome, Steve. Glad you figured out the other part.